# TensorFlow: implicit broadcasting in element-wise addition/multiplication

Tags: tensorflow

How does the implicit broadcasting in tensorflow using + and * work?

If i Have two tensors, such that

```
a.get_shape() = [64, 10, 1, 100]
b.get_shape() = [64, 100]
(a+b).get_shape = [64, 10, 64, 100]
(a*b).get_shape = [64, 10, 64, 100]
```

How does that become [64, 10, 64, 100]??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#arithmetic-operators), operations like `add` are broadcasting operation.

Quoting the [glossary](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/resources/glossary.html):

> Broadcasting operation
>
> An operation that uses numpy-style broadcasting to make the shapes of its tensor arguments compatible.

The numpy-style broadcasting is well documented in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

In brief:

> [...] the smaller array is “broadcast” across the larger array so that they have compatible shapes.
>
> Broadcasting provides a means of vectorizing array operations so that looping occurs in C instead of Python.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the broadcasting isn't doing what you intended. It's actually broadcasting both directions. Let me show you what I mean by modifying your example

```
a = tf.ones([64, 10, 1, 100])
b = tf.ones([128, 100])
print((a+b).shape) # prints "(64, 10, 128, 100)"
```

From this we see that it broadcasts by matching the last dimensions first. It's implicitly tiling `a` across it's third dimension to match the size of `b`'s first dimension, then implicitly adding singletons and tiling `b` across `a`'s first two dimensions.

What I think you expected to do was to implicitly tile `b` across `a`'s second dimension. To do that, you need `b` to be a different shape:

```
a = tf.ones([64, 10, 1, 100])
b = tf.ones([64, 1, 1, 100])
print((a+b).shape) # prints "(64, 10, 1, 100)"
```

You can use [`tf.expand_dims()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) twice on your b to add the two singleton dimensions to match this shape.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` style `broadcasting` is well documented, but to give a short explanation: the 2 tensors' shapes will be compared start from the last shape backward, then any shape lacked in either tensor will be replicated to be matched.

For example, with

```
a.get_shape() = [64, 10, 1, 100]
b.get_shape() = [64, 100]
(a*b).get_shape = [64, 10, 64, 100]
```

`a` and `b` have the same last shape==100, then the next to last shape of `a` is replicated to match `b` shape==64, `b` lacks the first two shapes of `a` and they will be created.

Note that any lacking shape must be 1 or absent, because the whole of lower-level shapes are replicated.